# SQL select if count

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, count

i have two tables
Incident (id, date)
Reminder (incidentID, type)
inner join on incident.id = reminder.incidentID

and i want to take incident.id only if it has more than 4 reminder.type = 15
what i think is

```
SELECT incident.id
FROM incident
INNER JOIN reminder ON incident.id = reminder.incidentid 
HAVING COUNT (reminder.remindertype = "something") >5
GROUP BY incident.incidentcode
```

The erroe i get is

> Line 6: Incorrect syntax near '='.

What can i do?

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT` doesn't work like that.

Try:

```
select incident.id
from incident
inner join reminder
on incident.id = reminder.incidentid
WHERE reminder.remindertype = "something"
group by incident.incidentcode 
having count (reminder.remindertype) >5
```

Comment: +1 but I believe it is good practice ( even required by most DBMS ) to have the GROUP BY before HAVING

Answer (score 2):

the `group by` clause should be declare before `having` clause

```
select incident.id
from incident
inner join reminder
on incident.id = reminder.incidentid
group by incident.incidentcode 
having count (reminder.remindertype) >5
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close:

```
select incident.id
from incident inner join
     reminder
     on incident.id = reminder.incidentid
group by incident.incidentcode 
having sum(case when reminder.remindertype = "something" then 1 else 0 end) >5
```

Your original syntax would not work in most dialects of SQL.  You need the conditional aggregation.